# How to iterate over a list all over without going out of range

Tags: list, range

Assume we have a list:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
x=0
```

For example when I do `list[x+15]` I get an "out of list range" error obviously, but what I am trying to do is: after the last element in list return back to the first element so `list[x+15]` would equal to 7 in my theory.

How can I iterate over the list again without getting out of range error?

I want other possible solutions other than rearranging the list like this:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] )
```

For example when I tried `list[x+10]` I expected 2 for the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1]. **Best Approach-: just do the modulo {%} with the length of the list you will get the result**

**Code:-**

```
lis=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2]  #Initialize a list
for i in range(13):     # Let's say for loop runs 13 Times which is greater than the list size
    print(lis[i%len(lis)])
```

**Output:-**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
2
1
2
```

**Your question:-**

list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] print(list[x+10])?

**#Code**

```
lis=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] 
x=0
print(lis[(x+10)%len(lis)])
```

**#Output**

```
2
```